# nginx + node.js = failed while connecting to upstream with iframely

Tags: node.js, nginx

I try to use Iframely. I install the self hosted version on my server ubuntu + nginx:
https://iframely.com/docs/host

When i start node like this:
`# node server`
 Iframely works well
Otherwise, i get a 502 bad gateway error.

## ERROR

In the log error:

```
2016/01/25 06:06:58 [error] 13265#0: *4476 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx, server: iframely.custom.com, request: "GET /iframely?url=http://coub.com/view/2pc24rpb HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8061/iframely?url=http://coub.com/view/2pc24rpb", host: "iframely.custom.com"
```

When i try:
`# curl -i 127.0.0.1:8061/iframely?url=http://coub.com/view/2pc24rpb`

It confirm the error:
`curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8061: Connection refused`

I begin with node and i understand that maybe node.js is not listening on port 8061.

When i try:
`netstat -pantu`

I don't see the port in question but others like this one used by another node.js app which works perfectly:

`tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:4567          127.0.0.1:60724         ESTABLISHED 12329/node`

## CONFIGURATION

My host configuration:

```
upstream iframely.custom.com {
        ip_hash;
        server localhost:8061;
        keepalive 8;
}
server {

        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name iframely.custom.com;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/iframely.custom.com;

        # Logs
        access_log /var/log/iframely.access_log;
        error_log /var/log/iframely.error_log;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

                proxy_pass http://iframely.custom.com/;
                proxy_redirect off;

                # Socket.IO Support
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

        # Exclude from the logs to avoid bloating when it's not available
        include drop.conf;

}
```

I have tried to change in the configuration localhost for 127.0.0.1 but it doesn't change anything.

How to keeps a node.js app alive: do i have to restart it forever?
Could it be a problem with ipv4 or ipv6?

I post this question on serverfault because i was thinking it's a problem with nginx configuration. But someone suggest i am wrong.

Thank you in advance for any help.
jb

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should make node application to listen port 8061 and it should be shown in "netstat -tpln" e.g.:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8061          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21151/node
```

Secondly, you should test it with curl. If the response is taken, then node server works perfectly.

Finally, shift focus to nginx.

Comment: Thank you for the test. Finally i solve the issue as you can see after.

Answer (score 1):

With only one backend, there's no benefit to using the `upstream` module. You can remove your `upstream` section and update your `proxy_pass` line like this:

```
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8061/;
```

It's also possible the backend is listening on the IP, but is not responding to the name "localhost". It's unlikely, but possible. But it must be listening on some IP address, so using the IP address is safer.

The advice above by Vladislav is good, too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually, i use multi node app. About my problem, upstream finally does seems to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the issue using forever: https://github.com/foreverjs/forever